# shared prefrences not cleared

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having problem with shared preferences.I have made a class user in which i have shared prefences related function and then calling that function form other class files.Shared prefrences are stored correctly but i am not able to delete them at signout.Signout is called from navigation drawer menu.I am going in delete function but it is not working.Any help would be highly appreciated as always.
Here is my user class containg shared prefrence functions.All functions working except removeToken

```
        package com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.UserModels;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;

        import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

        public class User {

          public static   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
            Context context;
            @SerializedName("token")
            @Expose
            private static String token;

            /**
             * No args constructor for use in serialization
             * 
             */
            public User(Context context) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
                sharedPreferences  = context.getSharedPreferences("user_token",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }

            /**
             * 
             * @param //token
             */
          /*  public User(String token) {
                super();
                this.token = token;
            }*/

            public static String getToken() {

                if(sharedPreferences.getString(token,null) != null){
                token = sharedPreferences.getString(token,null);
                };
                return token;
            }

            public void setToken(String token) {
                this.token = token;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("token",token).apply();
            }
            public static void removeToken(){
                if(sharedPreferences.contains("token")){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.remove("token").commit();
                   // editor.commit();
                  //  sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").apply();
                    System.out.println("shared preference deleting ");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("not contain key token ");
                }
            }

        }
```

I can see in logs shared prefrence deleting.but when i get token in other activity after deleting it token is there.Remove token is called in this api  file

```
          public static void logOut(Context context){
           // User user= new User(context);
            if(User.getToken() != null){
                User.removeToken();
                Intent a = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(a);
            }
        }
```

And after that i am getting token in main activity.Here is main activity file

```
package com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.Activities;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.UserModels.User;
    import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.R;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public String token = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        User user = new User(getApplicationContext());
        token = user.getToken();
        System.out.println("in main activity token is "+token);
        if (token != null) {
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnNewUser = findViewById(R.id.newUser);
        Button btnExistingUser = findViewById(R.id.existingUser);

        btnExistingUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });

        btnNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Comment: Try this: **editor.remove("token").apply.commit();**

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh either use commit or apply.Both will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you remove the SharedPreferences, because you're removing a single value from SharedPreferences properly.

Your issue is related to just one missing piece inside `removeToken()`

```
public static void removeToken(){
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("token")){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("token").commit();
        token = "";   //Missing this
        System.out.println("shared preference deleting ");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not contain key token ");
    }
}
```

You forgot to remove the stored token value from the token variable. This is required because the token variable inside User is a static variable, which means it'll persist even if the instance of User is destroyed or if a new instance of User is created.

Your `getToken()` code simply does a check to see if the token exists in your SharedPreferences. If it exists, then it'll modify the token variable with a new value. If it doesn't exist (which is what happens after removing) it'll return token. In other words, it's simply returning the old value that was stored before removeToken().

So your SharedPreference value is actually being cleared properly. You're simply fetching the old stored value in your new Activities.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my day with just one line.Awesome explanation too

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
      public static void removeToken(){
            if(sharedPreferences.contains("token")){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.clear().commit();
                System.out.println("shared preference deleting ");
            }else{
                System.out.println("not contain key token ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

> Use `remove()` method to remove `SharedPreference` token.

```
public static void removeToken(){
            if(sharedPreferences.contains("token")){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.remove("token");
                editor.clear().commit();
                System.out.println("shared preference deleting ");
            }else{
                System.out.println("not contain key token ");
            }
        }
```

> To Clear `SharedPreference` use:-

```
getSharedPreferences("user_token", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you logout, do call this method:

```
public static void logoutPrefs() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spreferences.edit();
    editor.remove("token");
    editor.commit();
}
```